# strange memcache behaviour on local apache server

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached

I'm currently having troubles about local deployment of my web service api. I'm using memcached with PHP Memcache extension. Here's the following behaviour;

I have a login function that firstly checks whether the user information is on memory with following code;

```
$cache = Memcacher::get_instance()->load( 'user.' . $email);
```

- if the cache exists, then it will return the variable `$cache` to be `true`.
- if the cache doesn't exist, then I'm saving it to the memory with following code;

  `$cache = Memcacher::get_instance()->save( 'user.' . $login['value']['email'], $login);`

the parameter `$login` is an associative array that holds user info.

After saving it to the memory, I try to re-login. However, it doesn't hold the info before I save to memcached server 3-4 times.

After 3-4 login, I get the login information from cache successfully.

Can anyone explain me that strange behaviour ? Is there any memcached configuration variable to prevent this ?

NOTE : I'm flushing the memory with restarting memcached with `sudo service memcached restart`
on Ubuntu

NOTE : Memcacher is a custom module that uses PHP Memcache extension's `set()` and `get()` function

NOTE : Here's the source code of [Memcacher](https://github.com/arascanakin/ariba/blob/master/library/memcache.class.php)

Comment: What does `Memcacher` look like .... ???

Comment: it looks like this : https://github.com/arascanakin/ariba/blob/master/library/memcache.class.php

Comment: What is the value of `Config::get('memcache_lifetime')` ???

Comment: How do you manage to concatenate a array with a string?

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating an array with a string. At points, it might not be true that $login is an array, therefore you will start receiving the information you have because the concatenation will work. But if it is an array, you will not be able to save the key in memcache. You will receive a notice, which i guess you ignore.

Comment: I wrote it wrong here it should be `$login['value']['email']`. Let me edit. Sorry for that

Comment: You might want to take into consideration checking for errors. One thing you definetly should do is returning the result of Memcache::set() which actually returns true for success and false for failure. I have been working with memcache for well over 1-2 years, i had no problem. this means that the problem is not expressed in your example, or some values don't match.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you recommend Memcache or Memcached PHP extension ?

Comment: I would go for memcached because of the enhanced functionality. Haven;t used memcache for some time, but mostly because i need support for CAS in most cases.